Keyframes suddenly not interpolating or being read on specific bone/rig
I have situation where I am trying to animate an IK rig and the animation is not being interpolated and sometimes not being read from the key frame. Other parts of the rig work fine. In fact I have an animation on the other foot, also IK, and that works fine. I can't figure out what might be the problem. I suspect it is some form of bug/corruption but I am really hoping someone might have run across this before and might know of a way to get around it.
Here is the position of the foot that is not being read:

And here is where it "should" be:


I am trying to animate the foot that has hooked underneath the bar (coloured), to resting on top of it.
The two screenshots are at the exact same frame.
Initially I blocked the positions and the keyframes are in bezier mode so they should interpolate, however they jump to the blocks without interpolation, and sometimes do not read at all.
Navigating backwards frame by frame along the timeline using the arrow key, the frames DO interpolate.
I tried inserting keyframes/per frame along to force the interpolation, but that did not work either.
I tried tweaking the pole target,
I tried restarting Blender,
I tried on a different computer (Windows) and that was worse. I couldn't actually move the rig at all (just the affected controller).
The other foot can be moved smoothly, but this one moves jerkily when I try to move it around.
The other controllers on the foot (ankle roll for example) moves smoothly.
I checked previous files using this rig. In one of them it has the problem, and in the other it does not.

My current option appears to try to reconstruct the whole thing, and import the rig that does not have the problem, but it's an immensely complex animation, I'm doubtful that will work. If anyone knows anything that could help I would be extremely grateful.

Having spent 4 or 5 hours puzzling over this I DID find what the culprit was;
It was a bone constraint that I had turned off that was still affecting the foot control:

I tried turning it off, AND turning off the influence, and neither had any effect, but that was what was causing the issues. Removing it entirely rectified the problem. I had used in for a previous animation and is not yet needed for this one.
I think this post should remain in case someone else runs in to the problem. Some kind bug, but too much hassle to report.

... and if you right-click the wrong way, blender will punish you!  ;)
